# Get one larger column from another columns in same table sql

Tags: mysql, select

I want to select a `name` that has more `received` than he `sent` from my table called `data_saver`

```
name      |  Received  | Sent
 -----------------------------
 Kiki      |     7      |    0
 Kim       |     4      |    5
 Lee       |     2      |    1
 John      |     3      |    6
```

In this case `Kiki` and `Lee` will be selected.
Please help me for selecting this in `MySQLi` table,
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If `Received` equals 1 when received otherwise it equals 0
, if `Sent` equals 1 when sent otherwise it equals 0,
than you only need to `sum()` the columns like this:

```
Select a.name , sum(a.Received) Received, sum(a.Sent) Sent 
from data_saver a 
group by a.name 
having sum(a.Received) > sum(a.Sent)
and a.name ='Kiki'
```

---

Comment: I just want for those who received more than they sent. equal and less than are not needed.

Comment: Thank you so much but Can you select only one please (the first user only) I mean any one of the users that receives more than he sent?

Comment: Add any condition to the having section.